# Create a list of unique values when referencing a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two worksheets in the same workbook. In Sheet1 *Column 1* is of expected stock barcodes, in Sheet2, *Column 2* is comprised of the barcodes which I scanned.

I wrote a formula in conditional formatting to check items *Column 2* and color them if they are not in *Column 1*, but I don't want to have to scroll through the entire list to see this.

What I want to do is populate a third (and fourth for quantity) column with only entries that are in *Column 2* and not *Column 1*, and if possible, list the number of times it was found in *Column 2*.

Example:

**Column 1**

```
bc123     
bc1234      
bc12345      
bc123456      
bc1234567
```

**Column 2**

```
bc12345      
bc123456      
bc56789      
bc67890      
bc67890
```

**Column 3** (Automatically populated with unique entries from column 2)

```
bc56789       1      
bc67890       2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well i know this is not what you asked, but an easy way to do this is add a Filter and Filter by color, then if you need unique, copy and paste that somewhere and use the "remove duplicates" button under the Data ribbon

Comment: In column3 enter `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)=0,COUNTIF(B:B,B1),"")` and fill down. you can then filter out blanks in col3

Comment: What you want...an excel formula...or....a vba code. And you should also try somethings and should post the code what you tried. visit [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Holmes and Tim. While those suggestions worked, I didn't want to have to use a filter each time I wanted to display that data. This spreadsheet is intended for the lady who checks the stock and I want to make it as easy for her as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, my VBA approach for your problem:

```
Public Sub findAndCount()

    Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim startSheet2, resultRow As Integer

    'Set sheets
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Set the start row of column from Sheet2
    startRow = 1
    resultRow = 1

    'Clear old result from column C & D of Sheet1
    sh1.Range("C:D").ClearContents

    'Loop all row of column 2 from Sheet2 until blank
    Do While sh2.Range("B" & startRow) <> ""

        'Find value in column A of Sheet1
        Set foundCell = sh1.Range("A:A").Find(sh2.Range("B" & startRow), LookIn:=xlValues)

        'If match value is not found
        If foundCell Is Nothing Then

            'Find result is already exist or not
            Set foundCell = sh1.Range("C:C").Find(sh2.Range("B" & startRow), LookIn:=xlValues)

            'If result is not exist, add new result. (Here, I show result in Sheet1, you can change it.)
            If foundCell Is Nothing Then

                'Set barcode
                sh1.Range("C" & resultRow) = sh2.Range("B" & startRow)

                'Set count
                sh1.Range("D" & resultRow) = 1

                'Increase result row
                resultRow = resultRow + 1

            'If already exist
            Else

                'Increase count
                foundCell.Offset(0, 1) = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1

            End If

        End If

        'Increase row
        startRow = startRow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you Nicolas, that worked!  
I did need to modify the integer 'startsheet2', it should have been 'startRow'.  
The only problem I have is if I run this macro more than once, it keeps adding the counts together. For instance if barcode 'abc' is found twice, and I run the macro twice, it will display 'abc  4'.  
Is there a way to change this aside from only running the macro once?  
Thank you.

Comment: OK, I got you. I modified my code by adding **"clearing statement for column C & D of Sheet1"**.

Comment: Ah! I obviously didn't think hard enough about that one. That was a very simple solution. Thank you @Nicolas, its working perfectly.